# "member.guild.username" is displayed as "undefined" in a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to welcome new people that join my Discord server using a bot. The message should look something like this:

> Welcome <nickname>

However, the code below sends this:

> Welcome undefined

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    var joiner = member.guild.username;
    member.guild.channels.get('601415083406393355').send("Welcome"+joiner); 
});
```

How can I display the member's username instead of `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```js
> var joiner = member.guild.username;
> ```

There is no `username` property of a [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild). You probably want `member.user.username`, which will return the username of the member that joined.